# Service Worker - Wait for clients.openWindow to complete before postMessage

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, service-worker-events

I am using service worker to handle background notifications. When I receive a message, I'm creating a new `Notification` using `self.registration.showNotification(title, { icon, body })`. I'm watching for the click event on the notification using `self.addEventListener('notificationclick', ()=>{})`. On click I'm checking to see if any `WindowClient` is open, if it is, I'm getting one of those window clients and calling `postMessage` on it to send the data from the notification to the app to allow the app to process the notification. Incase there is no open window I'm calling `openWindow` and once that completes I'm sending the data to that window using `postMessage`.

```
event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then((windows) => {
        if (windows.length > 0) {
            const window = windows[0];
            window.postMessage(_data);
            window.focus();
            return;
        }
        return clients.openWindow(this.origin).then((window) => {
            window.postMessage(_data);
            return;
        });
    })
);
```

The issue I am facing is that the `postMessage` call inside the `openWindow` is never delivered. I'm guessing this is because the `postMessage` call on the `WindowClient` happens before the page has finished loading, so the eventListener is not registered to listen for that message yet? Is that right?

How do I open a new window from the service worker and postMessage to that new window.

Comment: Hi,  @procedurally-generated did you ever get an answer to your question?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Oliver Nope, just added a delay. So do the postMessage after 3/4 seconds allowing the page to load.

Comment: It is a workaround but cant be the only solution...

Answer (score 2):

I stumble this issue as well, using timeout is anti pattern and also might cause delay larger then the 10 seconds limit of chrome that could fail.

what I did was checking if I need to open a new client window.
If I didn't find any match in the clients array - which this is the bottle neck, you need to wait until the page is loaded, and this can take time and postMessage will just not work.

For that case I created in the service worker a simple global object that is being populated in that specific case for example:

```
const messages = {};
....
// we need to open new window 
messages[randomId] = pushData.message; // save the message from the push notification
await clients.openWindow(urlToOpen + '#push=' + randomId);
....
```

In the page that is loaded, in my case React app, I wait that my component is mounted, then I run a function that check if the URL includes a '#push=XXX' hash, extracting the random ID, then messaging back to the service worker to send us the message.

```
...
if (self.location.hash.contains('#push=')) {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'Notification' in window && Notification.permission === 'granted') {
     const randomId = self.locaiton.hash.split('=')[1];
     const swInstance = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
     if (swInstance) {
        swInstance.active.postMessage({type: 'getPushMessage', id: randomId});
     }
     // TODO: change URL to be without the `#push=` hash ..
}
```

Then finally in the service worker we add a message event listener:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function handler(event) {
    if (event.data.type === 'getPushMessage') {
        if (event.data.id && messages[event.data.id]) {
            // FINALLY post message will work since page is loaded
            event.source.postMessage({
                type: 'clipboard',
                msg: messages[event.data.id],
            });
            delete messages[event.data.id];
        }
    }
});
```

`messages` our "global" is not persistent which is good, since we just need this when the service worker is "awaken" when a push notification arrives.

The presented code is **pseudo** code, to point is to **explain** the idea, which worked for me.

Comment: That's a good workaround. The best I've seen so far.

Answer (score -2):

```
clients.openWindow(event.data.url).then(function(windowClient) {
        // do something with the windowClient.
      });
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: @Zibri If you look at the sample code in my question you can see that this is already what I'm doing. The issue with this is that the code is executed once the window is open, not once the page has loaded. This means the code executes before the page registers a message listener, so this post message is never caught by the new tab.

Answer (score -3):

I encountered the same problem. My error was that I registered event handler on the window. But it should be registered on service worker like this:

```
// next line doesn't work
window.addEventListener("message", event => { /* handler */ });

// this one works
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => { /* handler */ });
```

See examples at these pages:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage

UPD: to clarify, this code goes into the freshly opened window. Checked in Chromium v.66.